# Notepad can find my string, but x64dbg can't

Tags: x64dbg

[image]

I open v2game.exe with notepad, and I can see string "teleport" occurs a bunch of times.

Now I open v2game.exe with x64dbg (not running the exe). x64dbg can't find the needed string. Why? Did I miss any step?

Comment: Is it UTF-16 in the executable? Try searching for a hex string with 00 between each letter code.

Comment: @Rup What do I do? Do I write like t00e00l00e in the search text box?

Comment: I meant between the ASCII bytes for teleport in hex. "teleport" is 74 65 6c 65 70 6f 72 74 in hex so I meant search for 74 00 65 00 6c 00 65 00 which is "tele" as UTF-16. Notepad understands UTF-16 so it might be automatically converting that into single characters for you.